# hash length for md5sum linux command

Tags: linux, hash, md5sum

Is there a way to control the output of md5sum command, Isn't it possible to  set how many bits the md5 output should be.

```
$ echo $var | md5sum -b
45819a662f88d80bfb35ad703ca8676f
```

but the output is too long, I want it to be shorter and I don't want to omit some part of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. An MD5 hash is 128 bits long; you cannot make it shorter without leaving part of it out.

Comment: I want to convert the output to decimal but Its not possible.

Comment: echo "ibase=16; 411361f2dfb5b013129dcf5aadcac59f" | bc
(standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: @FattanehTalebi Why? Is there something special you need to do with this value? Displaying it in decimal would make it even longer.

Comment: yes, I want to write 1 in the place of this value in a file, for example if the output is 2, I want to write "a" in the second char of that file @duskwuff

Answer (score 1):

[MD5 hash](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MD5) is always 128-bit (or 16 bytes).